# Zalenium test results are shown as "completed" while running on Browserstack

Tags: browserstack, zalenium

While running the test cases using zalenium and browserstack, the test results are shouwn in zalenium dashboard as completed, but not  passed, failed.

> **Steps**

1. I have added support to set test results based on [zalenium documentation](https://opensource.zalando.com/zalenium/)

[Zalenium add cookie to pass/faile the test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbAi9.png)

2. Added the support to set cookies to [browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/automate/capabilities) browser

[Add cookies to browserstack driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUCIf.png)

3. Added support to set test result in browserstack using it's [API](http://%20%20%20%20https://www.browserstack.com/automate/rest-api)

> **Results:**

Stil the test results of browserstack are shown as "completed"

[Test Results in Zalenium dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8C5G.png)

> **Note:**

Please note, that the local runs set the test result correct as failed/passed

> **QUESTION:**

Is there any way to set test result from browserstack to Zalenium local dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected, the pass/fail status has only been implemented for tests running in containers started by Zalenium.